# Move from ChangeNotifier to ValueNotifier in Flutter with Provider

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am currently working with an app in Flutter and I am using Provider as state management, I am using `ChangeNotifierProvider` of `<Data>` Data is a Class as `class Data extends ChangeNotifier` with a lot of info for my entire app and I modify my data using Methods and and then using `notifyListeners();` to update the data in several places of my App using two variables:

```
final Data provListen =Provider.of<Data>(context);
final Data provNoListen = Provider.of<Data>(context, listen: false);
```

Then I chose whenever to use the `provListen` or `provNoListen` depending if the parent widget needs to be updated or not.

I recently read that is better practice to use `ValueNotifier` instead of `ChangeNotifier` because you don't have to set the parameter `listen: false` for `ValueNotifier` but in the description of `ValueNotifier` it says:

> A ChangeNotifier that holds a single value.

So the question is, can I use `ValueNotifier` and pass a entire Class as a type? or should I keep using `ChangeNotifier` as my solution?

I will paste my data class for a reference but I don't know if it is needed for my question:

Here is my class:

```
class Data extends ChangeNotifier{
  FirebaseUser loggedInUser;
  FirebaseCaller firebaseCaller;
  List<NeighborDataModel> neighborhoodData = [];
  List<NeighborDataModel> searchDisplayData = [];
  List<NeighborDataModel> unchangedNeighborhoodData = [];
  List<PaymentDataModel> neighborPayments = [];
  List<Color> neighborColor = [];
  NeighborDataModel neighbor;
  PaymentDataModel payment;
  double currentOpacity = 1;
  bool absorbingTextFields = false;
  String email;
  String password;
  String recoverPasswordFeedback = '';
  String keyFeedback = '';
  TextEditingController nameController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController addressController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController emailController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController phoneController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController dateController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController keysController = new TextEditingController();
  Map neighborDisplaySettings = {
    'edit_icon_color': Colors.white,
    'icon_color': Colors.grey,
    'edit_data': false,
    'button_bar_visible': true,
  };

  Map filterSelection = {
    'inactive': true,
    'active': false,
    'all_neighbors': false,
  };

  /// Creates an instance of the Firebase User
  void firebaseUser(FirebaseUser loginUser) {
    loggedInUser = loginUser;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  /// Creates an instance of the Firebase Caller
  void firebaseCall(FirebaseCaller firebaseCall) {
    firebaseCaller = firebaseCall;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  /// Updates User Email
  void saveEmail(String newEmail) {
    email = newEmail;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  /// Updates User Password
  void savePassword(String newPassword) {
    password = newPassword;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  /// String to Diagnose Password Recovery
  void updatePasswordFeedback(String message) {
    recoverPasswordFeedback = message;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  /// String to Diagnose Key Adding
  void updateKeyFeedback(String message) {
    keyFeedback = message;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  /// Changes the filter selection
  void updateFilterSelection(Map newFilter) {
    filterSelection = newFilter;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  /// Updates all the Neighbors and the filtered Neighbors per search
  void updateNeighborsData(neighborsData) async {
    neighborhoodData = [];
    searchDisplayData = [];
    unchangedNeighborhoodData = [];
    unchangedNeighborhoodData.addAll(neighborsData);

    if (filterSelection['all_neighbors']) {
      neighborhoodData.addAll(neighborsData);
      searchDisplayData.addAll(neighborsData);
    } else if (filterSelection['active'] && filterSelection['inactive']) {
      for (NeighborDataModel thisNeighbor in neighborsData) {
        if (thisNeighbor.debt > 0 || thisNeighbor.debt == 0) {
          neighborhoodData.add(thisNeighbor);
          searchDisplayData.add(thisNeighbor);
        }
      }
    } else if (filterSelection['active']) {
      for (NeighborDataModel thisNeighbor in neighborsData) {
        if (thisNeighbor.debt == 0) {
          neighborhoodData.add(thisNeighbor);
          searchDisplayData.add(thisNeighbor);
        }
      }
    } else if (filterSelection['inactive']) {
      for (NeighborDataModel thisNeighbor in neighborsData) {
        if (thisNeighbor.debt > 0) {
          neighborhoodData.add(thisNeighbor);
          searchDisplayData.add(thisNeighbor);
        }
      }
    }
    Future(()=>notifyListeners());
  }

  /// Updates all the Payments for an specific Neighbor
  void updateNeighborsPayments(payments) async {
    neighborPayments.addAll(payments);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  /// Updates the Neighbor(s) of the search
  void updateSearcherData(newData) {
    searchDisplayData.clear();

    if (newData.isNotEmpty) {
      searchDisplayData.addAll(newData);
    } else {
      searchDisplayData.addAll(neighborhoodData);
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  /// Gets the Data of the Current Selected User
  void updateCurrentUser(NeighborDataModel currentNeighbor) {
    neighbor = currentNeighbor;
    nameController.text = '${neighbor.name} ${neighbor.lastName}';
    addressController.text = '${neighbor.streetName} ${neighbor.houseNumber}';
    emailController.text = neighbor.email;
    phoneController.text = neighbor.phone;
    dateController.text = neighbor.lastPayment['date'];
    Future(()=>notifyListeners());
  }
  /// Update Color gradient for Current Selected User
  void updateGradientForCurrentUser (List<Color> gradientList){
    neighborColor = gradientList;
    Future(()=> notifyListeners());
  }

  void updateCurrentPayment(PaymentDataModel currentPayment){
    payment = currentPayment;
    Future(()=>notifyListeners());
  }

  /// Greys out or Back to Normal the Login Screen
  void changeOpacityLogin(double newOpacity) {
    currentOpacity = newOpacity;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  /// Blocks the Text Fields for Password Recovery
  void textFieldPermission(bool newPermission) {
    absorbingTextFields = newPermission;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  /// Changes the text of each controller depending on the controllerName
  void editNeighborTextControllers(String newText, String controllerName) {
    switch (controllerName) {
      case 'nameController':
        nameController.text = newText;
        notifyListeners();
        break;
      case 'addressController':
        addressController.text = newText;
        notifyListeners();
        break;
      case 'emailController':
        emailController.text = newText;
        notifyListeners();
        break;
      case 'phoneController':
        phoneController.text = newText;
        notifyListeners();
        break;
      case 'keysController':
        keysController.text = newText;
        notifyListeners();
        break;
      case 'dateController':
        dateController.text = newText;
        notifyListeners();
        break;
    }
  }

  /// Change to Editing Mode
  void changeToEditMode(bool activate, context) {
    if (activate) {
      neighborDisplaySettings = {
        'edit_icon_color': Theme.of(context).indicatorColor,
        'icon_color': Theme.of(context).indicatorColor,
        'edit_data': true,
        'button_bar_visible': false,
      };
    } else {
      neighborDisplaySettings = {
        'edit_icon_color': Colors.white,
        'icon_color': Colors.grey,
        'edit_data': false,
        'button_bar_visible': true,
      };
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The idea is, extract all the properties of your notifier in a separate class, and use that as "value".

Comment: Hi Remi thanks for your answer, Provider is awesome by the way, I am kinda new with the concept can you share an example with my code? thanks in advance!

Comment: @MiguelChavez, have you visited [this blog](https://medium.com/coding-with-flutter/flutter-state-management-setstate-bloc-valuenotifier-provider-2c11022d871b)? It presents the difference of `ValueNotifier ` and `ChangeNotifier `.

Answer (score 0):

[ValueNotifier](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ValueNotifier-class.html) and [ChangeNotifier](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier-class.html) has similar functions. ValueNotifier can be used if you only need simple rebuild of widgets on data change. On the other hand, ChangeNotifier provides granular control with `notifyListeners()`. If one or the other works for you, it can be kept as-is if it fits your use-case.